# Rails lazy loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lazy-loading

I have an app which has an index page that shows currently 10 search results.  Rather than doing the standard lazy load with javascript, similar to the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised?view=comments) where new objects are shown when the user gets to the bottom of the page, I would like to have to page have a button on the bottom.  When that button is clicked, I would like the next 10 objects from the search results to show and so on.  Is there a tutorial for this/how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

you should use gem like

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari or  https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.

Comment: will these gems allow me to load the new objects on the same page with the previously loaded ones?  I guess this feature isn't necessarily standard pagination going from page to page with different results.

Comment: @user2184718 ok so you want to load new data with previous data on same page , then the Railscast you mentioned in your question is good to solve your problem, only change is that instead of writing jquery event on page end , provide an button to end of page and bind that event on click of that button

Comment: if you are working on opensource project , I am happy to send pull request for same.